# Как генерировать кнопки пагинации таблицы?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеем MongoDB и коллекцию в ней. Используется плагин mongoose-paginate для постраничной выборки.
Ответ приходит такого формата:

```js
{
    docs:Array[10],  // массив документов с нужной страницы
    limit:10,  // количество элементов на странице
    page:1,  // номер страницы
    pages:9,  // количество страниц
    total:88  // всего записей соответствующих критериям выборки
}
```

Для генерации кнопок написал такой фильтр:

```js
/*global angular*/
// /src/js/filters/range.filter.js

(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App')
    .filter('range', range);

  /**
   * Фильтр Angular
   *
   * @constructor
   * @name range
   *
   * @return {Function} Вернет фильтр для массива
   */
  function range() {
    /**
     * Фильтр создает из входного массива input массив чисел длиной total
     *
     * @method
     *
     * @param  {Array} input Пустой массив
     * @param  {Number} total Количество страниц
     * @param  {Number} current Текущая страница
     * @param  {Number} max Количество кнопок для показа
     *
     * @return {Array} Массив с числовыми элементами длиной max
     *
     * @example
     * <li ng-repeat="num in [] | range:88:2:5">{{num}}</li>
     * // создаст массив для вывода кнопок переключения страницы
     */
    return function(input, total, current, max) {
      console.log("total, current, max:", total, current, max);
      var total = parseInt(total);
      var current = parseInt(current);
      var max = parseInt(max);

      if(current > (total-max)){
        current = current-max;
      }

      for (var i=current; i<=(current+max); i++) {
        if(i <= total){
          input.push(i);
        }
      }

      return input;
    };
  }

  //range.$inject = [];

})();
```

Привожу скрины того что вышло:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Че то не могу придумать логику генерации. Поможете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в angularJS есть готовое [решение](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination), используйте его, не стоит придумывать новых велосипедов.

[здесь](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#writing-a-custom-pagination-controls-template) описание кастомных контролов.

А [здесь](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#example-asynchronous-setup) решение под Вашу задачу.

JS:

```
    .controller('UsersController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.users = [];
        $scope.totalUsers = 0;
        $scope.usersPerPage = 25; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page
        getResultsPage(1);

        $scope.pagination = {
            current: 1
        };

        $scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
            getResultsPage(newPage);
        };

        function getResultsPage(pageNumber) {
            // this is just an example, in reality this stuff should be in a service
            $http.get('path/to/api/users?page=' + pageNumber)
                .then(function(result) {
                    $scope.users = result.data.Items;
                    $scope.totalUsers = result.data.Count
                });
        }
    })
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="UsersController">
        <table>
            <tr dir-paginate="user in users | itemsPerPage: usersPerPage" total-items="totalUsers" current-page="pagination.current">
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <dir-pagination-controls on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
    </div>
```

Comment: Да пробовал я уже это. Не завелось. Придется много переписывать под это готовое решение. Проще уж додумать алгоритм. Но в любом случае спасибо за совет.

Comment: Взял (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) и все получилось. Но ваш совет тоже хорош, просто я начинаю только с ангуляром знакомиться.